# Is it possible to programatically set a filter in react-data-grid?

Tags: react-data-grid

I'm using react-data-grid with filters. It's all working just fine with a bunch of custom filters.

What I'd like to add now is a feature whereby in response to a user selecting an item in the grid, automatically set the filter to show only rows with the same value in the column matching the cell I've [double] clicked in.

I have sorted a click handler, I have the column name and filter value. But now I'm stuck as there seems to be no way to set a filter via code...?

Well...to be more specific, I'm pretty sure I can filter the data just fine, what I can't do it make the grid add the filter to the grid header.

I might be up for adding such a feature if someone can get me started with the right place in the code to begin looking at...